# Nothing will Wrap in PageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce, css, style

I have looked up documentation which suggests this should be easy, yet nothing works - why do none of the style elements below get the column header to wrap? It does not wrap in classic or lightning, in preview or on a record page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="ContactRolesMassEditExtension" >
    
    <apex:form>
        
        <apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit" >
            
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">               
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="saveButton" />                             
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OCRs}" style="table-layout:fixed" var="OCR"> 
              
                <apex:column style="word-wrap: break-all;" headerValue="L0o0o0o0o0o 0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0 o0o0o0o0o0o0 o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0 o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0ng"   >
                    <apex:outputField style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space:normal" value="{!OCR.Attended_First_Meeting__c}"></apex:outputField>
                </apex:column>
                                               
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            
        </apex:pageBlock>
        
    </apex:form>
    
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the myriad of text wrapping related tags seemed to do anything at all - but this worked just fine:

```
<apex:column >
     <apex:facet name="header">Marketing<br/>Program<br/>Contact</apex:facet>
     <apex:outputField value="{!OCR.Marketing_Program_Contact__c}"></apex:outputField>
</apex:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `headerClass` on the `<apex:column>` element?

As per the docs for the `style` attribute:

> The style used to display the column, used primarily for adding
> inline CSS styles. **Note that this value does not apply to the
> header and footer cells.**

Comment: In what way can we use “HeaderClass”?